# Bounding the principal complex logarithm

Tags: complex-analysis

Find an upper bound for

$$\left\vert{\rm Log}(z+ai)\right\vert$$

where $z\in\left\{Re^{i\theta}\,\colon 0\le\theta\le\pi, R>0 {\rm , R \,fixed}\right\}$, $a>0$  and ${\rm Log}(w) = \log{\vert w\vert} + i{\rm Arg}(w)$.

---

So I started by following this method:

\begin{align}
\left\vert{\rm Log}(z+ai)\right\vert &= \left\vert\log{|z+ai|} + i{\rm Arg}(z+ai)\right\vert \\
&\le \left\vert\log{|z+ai|}\right\vert + \left\vert i{\rm Arg}(z+ai)\right\vert \\ &= \left\vert\log{|z+ai|}\right\vert + {\rm Arg}(z+ai) \\
&\le \left\vert\log{(|z|+a)}\right\vert + {\rm Arg}(z+ai) \\
&= \left\vert\log{(R+a)}\right\vert + {\rm Arg}(z+ai)
\end{align}

But i'm not really sure how to bound the argument. Is this the best way of going about it or is there a nicer way to hand this?

Comment: If you fix a branch for the logarithm, the argument is already bounded.

Comment: @Starfall What do you mean by fix a branch?

Comment: The complex logarithm is a multivalued function, furthermore even if we restrict it to be single valued there is a discontinuity when we loop around the origin (the argument increases by $ 2\pi $ even if we get back to the same point.) To alleviate this, we introduce a branch cut, i.e we cut the complex plane by a ray through the origin. This amounts to restricting the argument of the complex logarithm to a certain interval.

Comment: @Starfall So how do we know which branch will give us the upper bound?

Comment: Typically it isn't very sensible to talk about the complex logarithm without clarifying the choice of branch, but in this question it doesn't matter - regardless of which branch you choose, the argument will always be bounded.

Comment: @Starfall sorry I don't really understand what you mean. Could you provide an example?

Comment: For instance, define $ \log(z) = \log|z| + i \arg(z) $ where $ \arg(z) $ is taken to be in $ (-\pi, \pi] $. Now, it is pretty clear that your argument is bounded.

Comment: Ah of course.. Thanks! Now is there any way to get rid of the absolute value on the first term?

Comment: You don't need to. The question asks you to find an upper bound, and you found an upper bound.